# Retrieving data with SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get data from SQL but i have some difficulties.

I want to retrieve all the customers that have made more than 2 invoices in which they have purchased the article x, but I want just the customers that have a total purchased of this article more then 2 units.

the query that I have written select just the customers that have made more than 2 invoices.

```
SELECT clientcode 
FROM   invoice f 
       INNER JOIN invoicedetails fd 
               ON f.idinvoice = fd.idinvoice 
WHERE  fd.itemcode IN ('FA02096103') 
       AND f.clientcode <> '00000' 
       AND CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dtfatures, 103), 103) >= 
           CONVERT(DATETIME, '20/01/2013', 103) 
       AND CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dtfatures, 103), 103) <= 
           CONVERT(DATETIME, '30/01/2013', 103) 
GROUP  BY clientcode 
HAVING Count(f.clientcode) >= 2
```

Comment: Converting to a varchar and back is about the least efficient way possible to truncate the time portion off of a date. What alternative I recommend depends on what version of sql server you have.

Comment: This query doesn't retrieve the ones with more than 2 invoices, it actually gets the ones with more than or equal two. The query doesn't match the description.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL Server? MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

The query you have written is not aligned with your description of it.

> You said: "I want to retrieve all the customers that have made more than 2
>   invoices in which they have purchased the article x, but I want just
>   the customers that have a total purchased of this article more then 2
>   units."

Here is how I would approach it. Say you have the following tables:

- Customers
- Invoices

  ```
  SELECT 
      c.CustomerID, SUM(i.Units) 
  FROM Customers c
  INNER JOIN Invoices i ON i.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
  WHERE 
      i.PurchasedItem = 'X'
  GROUP BY CustomerID
  HAVING SUM(i.Units) > 2
  ```

Make sure you understand how inner joins work though, inner join will return more records than you might expect if one of your tables contain duplicate records. So basically, for each record in table A, it will return all the matching records in table B, and if the next record in table A matches the same records in table B, they will appear again. Read more [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/02/09/sql-server-inner-join-returning-more-records-than-exists-in-table/)